# Changing part of image's source

Tags: jquery, html, image

I want to ask question is there possible way with jQuery to change a part of images' source ? The HTML code is simple as

```
<img src="numbers/gray/1.png" alt="green" width="44" height="46" /> 
<img src="numbers/gray/5.png" alt="green" width="44" height="46" />
```

and so[there are two folders '/gray/' and '/green/'], can I just (as an example clicking on link"Become green") to change the part "/gray/" of the source  with "/green/" while keeping each personal end of the source.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just try something like this:

```
$(function(){
  $('#myLink').click(function(){
    $('img').each(function(){
      var $this = $(this)
      $this.attr('src',$this.attr('src').replace('gray','green'))
    })
  })
})
```

Comment: you can consider: .replace(/\/gray\//g, '/green/'));

Answer (score 1):

you can use `replace()` to change just the grey to whatever you like

```
var src = $('img').attr('src').replace('gray','green');
```

check out this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/93sj7/1/)

```
$('img').attr('src', src);
```

Comment: You lost set the img src attribute with the var src you will obtain

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
$('img').attr('src').replace('gray', 'green');
```